# redirecting to thankyou page code check

Tags: php

The code below is form for mail..but em not able to redirect..can anyone check whats wrong in the code.. The thankyou.html  is in the same folder.
Thanks in advance

`http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

```
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($phone) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "ranjith@appleete.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Phone:\n$phone\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
         header('Location:thankyou.html'); 

    }    
    else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

?>'

Comment: `header('Location:thankyou.html');`, This has to be executed **before** any echo or printing stuff. This has to be called before any output has been printed.

Comment: instead of `header` change it to something like this: `echo "<script>location.href='thankyou.html'</script>";`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `mail` part works, so it's reaching the `redirect part`.

```
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
    // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
     echo "It tries to redirect"; exit; //Do you see this!?
     header('Location:thankyou.html'); 
     exit; //Add an exit to make sure your code stops here.
}
```

Also make sure there isn't anything like `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, or anything else that display things before the `header` part. It won't work when you already have output.

If this is called through an AJAX request you need to be aware that that the `thankyou` page `echo` the correct HTML and your AJAX callback function displays this HTML correctly.